# Using enumerate() to enumerate items with letters rather than numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, enumerate

I'm trying to use the built-in function enumerate() to label some points or vertices where each point is represented by its coordinates in a list(or set) of tuples which essentially looks like `{(4,5), (6,8), (1,2)}`

I want to assign a letter starting from "a" in ascending order to each tuple in this set, using `enumerate()` does exactly the same but It's written in a way that it returns the value of the index of each item so that it's a number starting from 0.

is there any way to do it other than writing my own `enumerate()`?

Comment: how many of those touples do you have?

Comment: What would be the output if the len list is greater than 26?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import string
tup = {(4,5), (6,8), (1,2)}
dic = {i: j for i, j in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, tup)}
```

This returns:

```
{'a': (4, 5), 'b': (6, 8), 'c': (1, 2)}
```

Comment: No nead for slicing, just `zip(string.ascii_lowercase,tup)` will already limit the result to the length of the shortest argument.

Comment: Yeah @tobias_k you're right. I've updated my answer now..Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 4):

This is `enumerate`'s signature.

```
enumerate(iterable, start=0)
```

Use `start` as 65 for `'A'` and 97 for `'a'`.

```
lst=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),...]
for idx,val in enumerate(lst,65):
    print(chr(idx),val)

A (1, 2)
B (2, 3)
C (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a way to get what you want, using `chr()`:

```
L = [(4,5), (6,8), (1,2)]
for k, v in enumerate(L):
    print(chr(65 + k), v)
```

Output :

```
A (4, 5)
B (6, 8)
C (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The enumerate function is defined as follow :

`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`

I think just have to write your own enumerate or an wrapper around enumerate.